# Polymorphism on type of Variables in C#

Tags: c#

I have a variable in a Class with the name of `Id`:

```
public class myClass
{
    GUID Id;
}
```

How can I have polymorphism on the `Id` variable to Get either an int type or a GUID type?

I want something like this, but it only gets GUID or int:

EDIT:

```
public class myClass
{
    Guid || int Id;
}
```

I want it so that the int or Guid is defined on initialization of the class.

Comment: This is not possible. What is your use case?

Comment: try showing the code as it would look, if it should be compiled :)

Comment: This is not Polymorphism by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic class.

```
public class MyClassName<TId>
{
  public TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

For int:

```
var myObject = new MyClassName<int>();
```

For Guid:

```
var myObject = new MyClassName<Guid>();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could make the class generic:

```
public class MyThing<T>
  where T : struct
{
  public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Which then can be used the following way:

```
MyThing<GUID>
MyThing<int>
```

But to give you a valid answer, it would certainly help to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It should be noted that making a class Generic like this, requires that you only have *one* variable type change based on the class type. Say I wanted MyThing to have a variable called animalCompanion of Type "Cat" if MyThing<CatLady> and Type "Dog" if MyThing<Man>, in addition to the GUID example above. The thought would be that if Cat and Dog extend a common ancestor (i.e. Animal) to simply use a "Animal" as the type of animalCompanion. However, what would one do in this scenario if the types "Cat" and "Dog" don't share a parent class? Go all the way up to Object?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to do that, but if you must, how about:

```
public class
{
    object Id;
}
```

or

```
public class
{
   private int _intId;
   private GUID _guidId;

   public int GetIntegerGuid()
   { 
       return _intId;
   }

   public int GetGuid()
   { 
       return _guidId;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in this case as polymorphism is something related to the object inheritance

*Polymorphism is the ability for an object to change its public interface according to how it is being used. When using inheritance, polymorphism is achieved when an object of a derived class is substituted where an instance of its parent class is expected. This uses a process known as upcasting. With upcasting, the object of the more specialised class is implicitly cast to the base class type required.*

more info [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Inheritance_4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `union` in **C** or a **discriminated union** type in **F#**; neither is possible to be defined in a nice syntax in **C#**.

This code provides you a generic class for using in the like scenarios:

```
public class Either<A, B>
{
    A _a;
    B _b;
    bool _isLeft;

    private Either() { }
    private Either(A a, B b, bool isLeft)
    {
        _isLeft = isLeft;

        if (_isLeft)
        {
            _a = a;
            return;
        }

        _b = b;
    }
    public Either(A a) : this(a, default(B), true) { }
    public Either(B b) : this(default(A), b, false) { }

    public A Left { get { return _a; } }
    public B Right { get { return _b; } }
    public bool HasLeft { get { return _isLeft; } }
}
```

You need to check `HasLeft` to see which value is actually there. One could use just an object field and some casting which I prefer to avoid in a statically typed language. There are other possible solutions too (using `dynamic` or `struct`) but this (IMHO) will do.

Note: One other way is to derive each `case class` from a `base class`. The bad thing (IMHO again) about that is you have to provide a separate overloaded functions for each `case class`.